Mount disk with an unknown filesystem
I am attempting to mount a disk via a USB docking station.
I have been informed that the disk was apart of a RAID1 system, however I see no sign of this so far.
Using fdisk -l I can see the disk:
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdi: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: 03ABYZ-011FA0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004db4d

Attempting to mount the drive with "mount":
$ sudo mount /dev/sdi /mnt/sata_disk/
mount: /mnt/sata_disk: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdi, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

In dmesg I can see:
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] EXT4-fs (sdi): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] EXT4-fs (sdi): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] EXT4-fs (sdi): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] FAT-fs (sdi): invalid media value (0x00)
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] FAT-fs (sdi): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] hfs: can't find a HFS filesystem on dev sdi
[Tue Sep 24 12:49:01 2024] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock

I have tried looking at /proc/mdstat, nothing there:
$ cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities :
unused devices: <none> 

'pvscan'  and 'vgscan' also return nothing:
$ sudo pvscan -v
  No matching physical volumes found
$ sudo vgscan -v
  No volume groups found.
$ sudo lvscan -v
  No volume groups found.

Any help would be much appreciated.
$ lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid /dev/sdi
  SIZE FSTYPE MODEL                 NAME
                                        SERIAL       UUID
465.8G        WDC WD5003ABYZ-011FA0 sdk 152D20337A0C


Do you see any partition in fdisk -l ? Perhaps the partition will provide you some insights about the FS format. I would have tried vgchange -ay before checking if PV/VG/LV are present.

No partition in fdisk -l , I also checked with lsblk. Just tried vgchange -ay, then restarted the docking station and I get the same result with PV/VG/LV

"a part of a RAID1" I am not sure If could find any usefull data. IMHO you would need all disks from this RAID1.

Even with RAID, you normally use partitions, but some do not create any partitions. Then drive is like an old floppy drive. Is it actually seen as fd0? sudo udisksctl mount -b /dev/fd0

Find out details about the hardware and OS of the old system. Did it use a special RAID controller? Which type?

lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid and see what file system type reports as

Try mdadm --query /dev/sdi and/or mdadm --examine /dev/sdi to see if the disk contains any of the RAID metadata formats recognized by mdadm (Linux native RAID superblock format, industry standard DDF and Intel's IMSM). This is a bit more extensive check than just looking at /proc/mdstat.

@ron that reports back an empty fstype, maybe they're not from a RAID system. I'll add the output to the bottom of the post.

The fdisk -l output indicates that the drive has a MBR/dos partition table on it, but just that the table has no partition entry in it. Looks like it has been "re-initiailized"?

It might be a MD RAID, you would assemble that with mdadm --assemble --scan.
The RAID superblock will say how many devices that array consisted of, and if some are missing, the array will refuse to start. The --run option can be added to start if the minimum number of disks is present, which for a RAID1 would be one.

There's no evidence that it might be mdraid`

mdraid needs an explicit scan via mdadm, simply looking at /proc/mdstat is not sufficient. The initramfs can scan if it was built with mdadm support, but if the root is not on mdraid, there is no guarantee that it does so. The other options like LVM raid are covered by the question.

Thank you; would you mind adding this detail to your answer?
